# Duplicate symbols for architecture arm64 -objc

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arm64

I added some .m, .h files(include xxxController.m, xxxController.h) and libraries(include abc.a) to my xcode project same as the sample project which runs very well but this error occured:

> duplicate symbol '*OBJC_IVAR*$xxxController.xxx' in:
> /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/xxx.build/Debug-iphoneos/xxx.build/Objects-normal/arm64/xxxController.o
>
> ../lib/xxx/lib/abc.a(xxx.o) ld: 15 duplicate symbols for architecture
> arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
> see invocation)

I changed enable testability option and no common blocks option to NO but still fail to build.
Also there are no duplicates in the compile source and removing derived data or cleaning build folder didn't work for me.

And when I remove '-Objc' in Other Linker Flags, it occurs 'Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_FIRInstallations' error. How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you find the solution for this ?